# standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "operation not permitted"

Tags: python, docker

I was trying to run a django-rest-framework app on docker using `python 2.7 & django = 1.11` image and `postgerss` images. here is my  `docker-compose.yml` file.
I am running Docker on windows 10 Enterprise build 1909

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: xxxxxxx
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xxxxxx
      POSTGRES_DB: xxxxxx
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
      - pgdata_v:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata:Z
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
  web:
    build: .
    command: /app/scripts/runserver.sh
    environment:
      ENV: local
      WERKZEUG_DEBUG_PIN: 'off'

      DB_USER: xxxxxx
      DB_PASSWORD: xxxxxx
      DB_NAME: xxxxxx
      DB_PORT: 5432
    volumes:
      - ./config/:/app/config/
      - ./v1/:/app/v1/
      - ./scripts/:/app/scripts/
    ports:
      - "8005:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db

volumes: 
  pgdata_v:
    external: true
```

And here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:2.7

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV ENV local

RUN mkdir -p /app/scripts/
WORKDIR /app
ADD ./requirements /app/requirements/

RUN pip install -U setuptools
RUN pip install distribute==0.7.3
RUN pip install urllib3==1.21.1 --force-reinstall
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements/base.txt

RUN mkdir -p /app/static/
ADD ./manage.py /app/
ADD ./config/ /app/config/
ADD ./scripts/ /app/scripts/
ADD ./cert/ /app/cert/
ADD ./v1/ /app/v1/

RUN chmod 755 /app/scripts/runserver.sh

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["/app/scripts/server.sh"]
```

while running it i get the error `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "operation not permitted"`

I have looked at some answers on StackOverflow and github but could not fix it.

Comment: Your `chmod` command is modifying `runserver.sh`, but your `CMD` runs `server.sh`.  Should these be the same?

Comment: It's also not impossible that a bind-mounted data volume could be mounted `noexec`.  I don't think that's the default setup but I could imagine it.  Does deleting the `volumes:` for the `web` container from your `docker-compose.yml` help?

Comment: @DavidMaze i dont think that matters because in the `docker-compose.yml` `runserver.sh` is being called. and also I have tried running it as you said but no difference

Comment: Deleting `volumes` doesnot solve the error it introduces another error for the database. It cannot access pgdata folder created. But still the `noexec` error will be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried many fixes but none could work for me so I moved to WSL(Windows sub-system for Linux). I set up my environment there, cloned my repository there and it is working now. To use Docker on the WSL I used this [post](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly#configure-docker-for-windows)
This might help others facing similar issue like me.